# Is there a performance difference between PDO fetch statements?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

like in

```
/* Exercise PDOStatement::fetch styles */
print("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: ");
print("Return next row as an array indexed by column name\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
print("\n");

print("PDO::FETCH_BOTH: ");
print("Return next row as an array indexed by both column name and number\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
print_r($result);
print("\n");

print("PDO::FETCH_LAZY: ");
print("Return next row as an anonymous object with column names as properties\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
print_r($result);
print("\n");

print("PDO::FETCH_OBJ: ");
print("Return next row as an anonymous object with column names as properties\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print $result->NAME;
print("\n");
```

Well the default are FETCH BOTH, I am wondering if FETCH ASSOC is faster when I'm going to fetch a lot of data; or they are the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 48):

I wanted to know the answer to this question, so I wrote a quick [benchmark script](https://gist.github.com/stephen-hill/5508483).

I suggest you run this benchmark on your own server, however, this is a typical result on my setup, for single row results:

1. PDO::FETCH_ASSOC - 936 ms
2. PDO::FETCH_BOTH - 948 ms
3. PDO::FETCH_NUM - 1,184 ms
4. PDO::FETCH_OBJ - 1,272 ms
5. PDO::FETCH_LAZY - 1,276 ms

For large data sets, these results are typical:

1. PDO::FETCH_LAZY -  5,490 ms
2. PDO::FETCH_NUM -   8,818 ms
3. PDO::FETCH_ASSOC- 10,220 ms
4. PDO::FETCH_BOTH - 11,359 ms
5. PDO::FETCH_OBJ -  14,027 ms

See the comments on git hub, fetching all the rows does change the test.

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on the downvote. This is the only quantitative answer to this question so far.

Comment: It's a pain to have a downvote without an explanation, I know. Well, with my upvote, you're back to square one. I mean square zero. 

Thanks for the test and the script. Perhaps one enhancement. I think that using the data should be part of the test, as accessing an array or an object may also result in a difference in timing.
In addition, there may even be a difference in requesting data from a large array or a large object.

Comment: Note. Laziness will cost more if you pull all the params from the result. I guess it useful when you get a huge response and need only a fraction.

Comment: This is a horrible test, as it always happens with tests. Even the author admits that changing conditions changes the test results. Which means this test is unreliable and numbers are useless

Answer (score 4):

> I am wondering if FETCH ASSOC is faster when I'm going to fetch a lot of data; or they are the same?

**Do not** fetch a lot of data, when you don't need it. that's all.

Once you need it - microscopic difference between these methods would be your least concern.

Comment: It is not an answer for the question

Comment: @your-common-sence I agree with you answer but it is an answer for another question

Comment: Some questions shouldn't be answered. If someone asks "how to shoot myself in the foot", the answer is "don't do it!", not a detailed instruction on how to actually make one crippled for the rest of their life.

Comment: You are comparing a fly with an elephant. In some creasy cases even a minor performance is important.

Comment: NOT in case when there is a FUNCTIONAL difference between approaches. One should choose the fetch mode that is best for their purpose, not one which has an imaginary performance benefit.

Answer (score 4):

The benchmark script posted in another answer is counting prepare() and execute() to the time so I write a script for testing only fetch time. I have MySQL database, with about 100000 rows of real data. LongRow contains TEXT column (about 4kB of data per row). ShortRow is (30 bytes per row). FETCH_INTO uses predefined class with all column properties. PHP version 5.4. MySQL 5.5.35. One thing is missing here: average of some runs.

```
Array
(
    [Items: 10] => Array
        (
            [ShortRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.0001068115234375
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.00013899803161621
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (STR8)] => 6.0081481933594E-5
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 5.8174133300781E-5
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 9.2029571533203E-5
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 9.8943710327148E-5
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.00011897087097168
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 6.3180923461914E-5
                )

            [LongRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.00012779235839844
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.00016498565673828
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (TEXT)] => 4.9829483032227E-5
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 4.3153762817383E-5
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 0.00010180473327637
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 0.00010895729064941
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.00013399124145508
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 4.3869018554688E-5
                )

        )

    [Items: 100] => Array
        (
            [ShortRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.00081610679626465
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.0011789798736572
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (STR8)] => 0.00040292739868164
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 0.00041294097900391
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 0.00067806243896484
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 0.00076103210449219
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.00092482566833496
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 0.00043201446533203
                )

            [LongRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.0010471343994141
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.0013670921325684
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (TEXT)] => 0.00037693977355957
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 0.00030612945556641
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 0.00079894065856934
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 0.00094914436340332
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.0011270046234131
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 0.00031089782714844
                )

        )

    [Items: 1000] => Array
        (
            [ShortRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.0082287788391113
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.0099248886108398
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (STR8)] => 0.0037147998809814
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 0.0038070678710938
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 0.006443977355957
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 0.0070838928222656
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.008652925491333
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 0.0039060115814209
                )

            [LongRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.0092909336090088
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.011745929718018
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (TEXT)] => 0.0031650066375732
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 0.0025970935821533
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 0.0068809986114502
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 0.0087978839874268
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.010183811187744
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 0.0026650428771973
                )

        )

    [Items: 10000] => Array
        (
            [ShortRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.067224025726318
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.086459159851074
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (STR8)] => 0.03191089630127
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 0.031462907791138
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 0.047988891601562
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 0.05333399772644
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.065713882446289
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 0.028834819793701
                )

            [LongRow] => Array
                (
                    [FETCH_INTO] => 0.12389183044434
                    [FETCH_OBJECT] => 0.15812706947327
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (TEXT)] => 0.03816294670105
                    [FETCH_COLUMN (INT)] => 0.035914897918701
                    [FETCH_NUM] => 0.1117901802063
                    [FETCH_ASSOC] => 0.10923099517822
                    [FETCH_BOTH] => 0.12394094467163
                    [FETCH_LAZY] => 0.030914068222046
                )

        )

)
```

Here is a code too:

```
    //Code is missing connect to DB
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    class testModel1 {
        public $id;
        public $invoice;
        public $transaction;
        public $creditedInvoice;
        public $amount;
        public $payment_type;
        public $currency;
        public $created;
        public $timestamp;
    }

    class testModel2 {
        public $id;
        public $cid;
        public $c_amount;
        public $object;
        public $person;
        public $date;
        public $type;
        public $invoice_type;
        public $version;
        public $templateInvoice;
        public $account;
        public $variable_symbol;
        public $number;
        public $accounting_year;
        public $amount;
        public $currency;
        public $comment;
        public $data;   //is a text column (avg size about 4kB)
        public $created;
        public $modified;
        public $timestamp;
    }
    $items = array(10,100,1000,10000);
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $ivStmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `invoices_paying` LIMIT $item");
        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $out = array();
        $testModel1 = new testModel1();
        $ivStmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $testModel1);
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch()) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_INTO'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetchObject()) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_OBJECT'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetchColumn(5)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_COLUMN (STR8)'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetchColumn(0)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_COLUMN (INT)'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_NUM'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_ASSOC'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_BOTH'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_LAZY'] = $end-$start;

        $table['Items: '.$item]['ShortRow'] = $out;
    }
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $ivStmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `invoices` LIMIT $item");
        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $out = array();
        $testModel2 = new testModel2();
        $ivStmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $testModel2);
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch()) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_INTO'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetchObject()) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_OBJECT'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetchColumn(17)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_COLUMN (TEXT)'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetchColumn(0)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_COLUMN (INT)'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_NUM'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_ASSOC'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_BOTH'] = $end-$start;

        $ivStmt->execute(array('items'=>$item));
        $start = microtime(true); 
        while($id = $ivStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) {
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        $out['FETCH_LAZY'] = $end-$start;

        $table['Items: '.$item]['LongRow'] = $out;
    }
    print_r($table);
```

Answer (score 2):

ASSOC, BOTH and OBJ are generally the same, except that they return a different structure. No performance differences there.

LAZY does some sort of lazy loading. PDO::FETCH_LAZY creates the object variable names as they are accessed. This means that you get the performance penalty only when you access the properties, not when calling fetch(). This is useful if you use only a part of the returned data.

Comment: Is there any situation where lazy-loading decreases performance?

Comment: well i haven't actually tried it, but i am sure that the difference are minor. but i don't now really.

Comment: "This is useful if you use only a part of the returned data." Why would you query for data you aren't going to use? Or is it a matter of better get too much rather than having to query again?

Comment: Note: `PDO::FETCH_LADY` cannot be used with `fetchAll()`

Comment: @MDSayemAhmed , Yes, when you access all the properties you actually use the laziness for nothing. The laziness is then Just an extra work.

Answer (score -2):

Last answer is silly ("do no fetch...."): what if you have to transform data for a big table, or interface dbs tables?

I changed the benchmarking code above, because it was not testing corretcly IMHO (one single fetch per loop is not enough ;-) ), I replaced it by 10000 records x 100 loops per fetch type.

I added Fetch_class which was the question I had for myself.
I added a real class to be certain the latter test was correct.

results (sorted):

```
Array
(
    [Lazy] => 88.43896484375
    [Num] => 281.11694335938
    [Assoc] => 310.59375
    [Class] => 384.8310546875
    [Obj] => 395.36401367188
    [Both] => 411.62109375
)
```

Lazy value is incomplete, since there is no access.
but "Both" actually **HAS** impact

> here is the modified gist [modified Benchmark code](https://gist.github.com/boussou/0741b7a4be02c49c5471)

Comment: The other answer also states "Once you need it [big data] - microscopic difference between these methods would be your least concern." Some PHP users have no common sense and would use not **the method which is appropriate for their needs** but one which is imaginary "faster".

Comment: Right. 
Ie I would always recommend Assoc because you don't want Num access, even if it faster. And I found that Assoc is always better than Class because you could "miss" data if prop is not defined.